# visual studio 2019 design page is not showing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

i Opened the visual studio 2019 after long time. when i open my previous C# windows form project on visual studio it doesn't show design page.. could somebody help me to open it please?

[image]

Comment: In the Visual Studio Installer do you have ".NET desktop development" installed?

Comment: @Jesse i don't know actually. i cannot remember it. But after executing this project. it shows the software as normal

Comment: @Jesse when i create a new project. it contains a designer page.. But older project doesn't have one

Comment: Is `copied.cs` contain the designable class?  What happens when you right click on `copied.cs` (or whatever file contains the designable class).  Is there a `View Designer` option?  BTW, `copied.Designer.cs` is normally hidden (underneath `copied.cs`).  I suspect that your `.csproj` may be corrupted.  It's fixable if you know what you are doing, but easy to corrupt (perhaps even more) if you don't.  Always back up the whole project if you want to try to fix it.

Comment: @Flydog57 no there is not a `view designer` option

Comment: Are you showing a _Solution Explorer_ view.  You shouldn't even see `ConcluttionAPPWATCHERS.csproj` in the Solution explorer.  Something is hosed in your solution and/or your project.  Did you open this up by double clicking the appropriate `.SLN` file?  I see a view close to what you show if I open VS and then say `File::Open Folder`

Comment: @Flydog57 i didn't double click it, i opened visual studio and open this project

Comment: Close it, open the SLN file (File::Open::Project/Solution, pick the SLN file).  If that doesn't work, you may need to figure out how to fix the either or both of the SLN and/or CSPROJ files

Comment: i opened the project using sln file.. now it is showing the design page.. thank a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you opened your projects *Folder*.  What you want it the *Solution*.

Close the current view (`File` -> `Close Folder`) and then `File` -> `Open` -> `Project/Solution` and open the `.SLN` file (or, double-click the `.SLN` file in the Windows Explorer).